# How can I make a Telegram bot listen to messages from a different chat with Python?

Tags: python, telegram

I want to make a Telegram bot with Python and I want it to constantly read messages from a different private chat. I want to find a way to make the bot receive all the messages which I receive in the given chat. My struggle is redirecting the messages from one private chat to the chat with the bot. Is it possible to do it? If yes, how can it be done?

I have tried googling the subject, but I haven't found any satisfying answer.

Comment: Why dont you show what you have done so far and tried and what errors you get

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know whether that thing is even possible

Answer (score 0):

Check this package :
https://python-telegram-bot.org/
You would juste have to add a message handler to your bot instance.

You have to talk to telegram BotFather to get a token. Then you have to create a instance of a bot in your code and subscribe to new messages

```
from telegram.ext import Update, MessageHandler, Filters

# Define a function to handle the messages that the bot receives
def message_handler(update, context):
    # Get the message from the update
    message = update.message

    # Print the message to the console
    print(message.text)

# Create the Updater and pass it the bot's token
updater = Updater("TOKEN", use_context=True)

# Get the dispatcher to register handlers
dp = updater.dispatcher

# Add a message handler that will be called for any message
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, message_handler))

# Start the bot
updater.start_polling()

# Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
# SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
# start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Is it new messages in BotFarther or new messages on account?